# Can the amphtml link tag use relative href instead of absolute?

Tags: amp-html

Our cms hosts multiple domains and generally its much easier to use relative paths whenever possible. I'm just wondering if its ok to have something like: `<link rel="amphtml" href="/path/to.amp.html" />`
instead of an absolute http(s) url

Comment: I don't think this will work since when Google fetches the AMP pages from their cache, it might lead to a 404 because any AMP pages in the Google search results links to `https://www.google.ca/amp/<amphtml URL>`.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Andrew It seems that this issue was fixed, therefore you could use relative url (by setting the < base > tag). more info: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2277#issuecomment-275204337 and a working example: https://blog.tomayac.com/categories/technical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if it happens to work, it is much better to use absolute links for this purpose because the document could appear in another context (e.g. a proxy) and then resolving the relative link could fail.

The example provided in the spec is absolute:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#amp-document-discovery